# How to remove every line that doesn't contain special/specific characters in Notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++, notepad

I would like the remove every line that doesn't contain the next characters:

**! ? # * $ [ ] { } - _ ( )**

*How should I do that, please?*

Answer (score 0):

- Find what: `^[^!?#*$\[\]{}\-_()]+\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`

`[^!?#*$\[\]{}\-_()]` is a negative character class that match a character that is not `!, ?, #, *, $, [, ], {, }, -, _, ( or )`